# Spring JPA double creation

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

For visual brevity, I have a parent-child of Vendor-EDITypes in a O:M relationship.  What I cannot explain is, if line below that is commented out is included EDITypes a0-a3 are created twice.  It is impressive but not totally understood how saving the vendor automatically creates the EDITypes once, as listed below. Nor how adding the EDITypes to the vendor force the creation of the EDITypes twice. I would have expected to have to save the EDITypes.  How is this controlled bc of the O:M?  Must I always save on the M side?

```
EDIType a0 = new EDIType(abuyers,"receiving00-xls");a0.setVendor(abuyers);
EDIType a1 = new EDIType(abuyers,"receiving01-xlsx");a1.setVendor(abuyers);
EDIType a2 = new EDIType(abuyers,"receiving02-pdf");a2.setVendor(abuyers);
EDIType a3 = new EDIType(abuyers,"creditMemo00-xls");a3.setVendor(abuyers);
List<EDIType> eList = Arrays.asList(a3,a2,a1,a0);
//abuyers.getEdis().addAll(eList);  //when commented out correct. else double creation
this.add(abuyers);
```

Answer (score 0):

It just like insert EDIType table with Foreign key as primary key of Abuyers. When insert is done, you do not need to change anything on Abuyer.

After all, it's just ORM which tries to deal with SQL table in an object-oriented way but still underlines mechanism is still SQL table.